# Why does Example A Compile and Example B Errors with "initializer element is not constant"

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c11

Edit:
I had made a few assumtions such as the static variable would be created and initialised once at runtime first time function was called.

I now know this is not the case and will now just define a static and return its pointer and have an init function thats called once at the start of the program, so is essentially the same as I was doing it when I was using globals but keeping it out of global scope.

Original:

I'm trying to avoid Global Variables as is generally suggested, but needing some static data that I can refer to in multiple functions without having to constantly pass an object to every single function (Though if this ultimatly doesn't work i may have to resort to that)

Another potential advantage is since most of the functions I'm using this for are to be called very often, only initializing once for data that should never change should minimise performance loss.

The method i've come up with is creating a static variable and initing it once, if i need to use it in a single function i'll init within the function directly and then use it, if i need it in multiple functions i'll init it in a seperate static function that the others can call for the pointer

Edit:
WINDOWS is a custom macro

```
#ifndef WINDOWS
  #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define WINDOWS
  #endif
#endif
```

Also the compiler is MinGW 64bit

Example A Compiles Fine but Example B Throws an Error "initializer element is not constant"

Example A:

```
static ProgramPath getPath() {
  ProgramPath result;
    // Get Executable Path    
#ifdef WINDOWS
  GetModuleFileName(NULL, result.executablePath, sizeof(result.executablePath));
#endif

  // Seperate Path and Executable into Seperate Variables
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof result.executablePath; ++i) {
    // Convert \ to /
    if (result.executablePath[i] == 0x5c) {
      result.executablePath[i] = 0x2F;
    } else if (result.executablePath[i] == 0x0) { // 0x0 means we've reached end of string.
      unsigned int j;

      // Get Executable Name Sub String
      for (j = i - 1; j > 0; --j) {
        if (result.executablePath[j] == 0x2F) { // Stop when we reach a /
          result.executableStringLen = i - j;
          memcpy(&result.executable, &result.executablePath[j + 1], result.executableStringLen); // Copy Executable SubString into correct variable
          break;
        }
      }

      result.executableStringLen = ++j;

      // Remove Executable from Path
      for (; j < i; ++j) {
        result.executablePath[j] = 0x0;
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  CA_VERBOSE_DEBUG("Executable: %s", executable);
  CA_PRINT_DEBUG("Executable Path: %s", executablePath);

  return result;
}

static inline ProgramPath *getPathInfo() {
  static ProgramPath programPath = getPath();
  return &programPath;
}
```

Example B:

```
static GraphicsInfo getGraphicsInfo() {
  GraphicsInfo result;

  result.internalPixelFormat = GL_BGRA;
  result.internalPixelType = GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV;

  // Get Preferred Internal Pixel Format
  if (glGetInternalformativ) {
    const GLenum preferedInternalFormats[4] = {
      GL_RGB,
      GL_BGR,
      GL_RGBA,
      GL_BGRA
    };

    GLint test;
    // Check for Internally Supported Formats and Use Best One
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; --i) {
      // Check for Prefered
      glGetInternalformativ(GL_RENDERBUFFER, preferedInternalFormats[i], GL_INTERNALFORMAT_PREFERRED, 1, &test);

      if (test == GL_TRUE) {
        result.internalPixelFormat = preferedInternalFormats[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

static inline GraphicsInfo *CA_getGraphicsInfo() {
  static GraphicsInfo result = getGraphicsInfo(); // Error Occurs Here
  return &result;
}
```

I have also tried commenting out the bulk of the code in Example B to no avail

Comment: Neither is OK. `static` variables must be initialized with constant expressions, and a function call is not one of these.

Comment: Looks like Java: unreadable, IMHO.

Comment: It seems that your are testing your code with a very particular compiler, one that defines the macro `WINDOWS`. And then you conclude something about the conformance of your code. If this is really a Microsoft compiler, be warned that it doesn't even adhere to the C99 standard.

Comment: WINDOWS was a custom macro I'll edit the topic and also state the compiler, which is MinGW 64bit.

Comment: You unconditionally define `WINDOWS` (to a value that might be either true or false), then you test whether it's *defined*. I suggest defining `WINDOWS` in an `#ifdef`, so it's defined if and only if you're compiling for Windows. (Or use some other predefined macro that's defined for both `_WIN32` and `_WIN64`; I'd be surprised if such a macro didn't already exist.)

Comment: I realise how silly i was with that definition now, i'll update it, it was one of the earliest thing's i did in C and had yet to be caught out by it

I've yet to find a generic windows variable which is why i've been using that.

Comment: The posted code does not even come close to compiling, must less cleanly compiling.  Have you forgot to include the `#include` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a variable with `static` storage from the return value of a function:

```
static inline GraphicsInfo *CA_getGraphicsInfo() {
    static GraphicsInfo result = getGraphicsInfo(); // Error Occurs Here
    return &result;
}
```

The 2 code fragments deal with different structures for which you have not provided the definition, neither should compile, but note that if `WINDOWS` is not defined, `getPath` manipulates an uninitialized structure `result`, so anything can happen, including the compiler playing tricks on you.

It is also possible that, since both functions are defined as `static inline`, the compiler only reports the error when it actually tries to expand `getPath` inline at a call site, and still reports the error with a the location at the definition of the inline function.

Furthermore, here are some problems with `getPath`:

- it invokes `memcpy` on potentially overlapping objects, this also invokes undefined behavior: use `memmove` instead.
- `result.executableStringLen = ++j;` is incorrect and should be removed. If the `'/'` was found, the length has already be updated, but you should initialize it before the search to `result.executableStringLen = i;`
- If the `'/'` was not found, you effectively clear the array except for the very first byte.  You should instead start from `j = result.executableStringLen`.

Comment: I played around with non static and non inline functions results wer the same.

I didn't think the definition of the structs would matter as they're both pretty simple

Thanks for the into on getPath I shall go ahead and update my code, I also didn't know the memmove command existed.